# How to set multiple sideToggles in the same space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Is there a way to put 3 sideToggles to slide different content in the same space of the screen depending on which chosen?[image]

So basically when I click on toggle2 I want toggle1 content to disappear/slide back and show the toggle2 content. It doesn't have to be slideToggle though I don't know any other method.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's best to give at least a little bit of your code. There are lots of ways for this kind of question but let us see first what you've done on your own.

Comment: I tried using variations of slideToggle though to be honest i would be ashamed to post it since it didn't do anything similar i wanted it to.